# Count amount of pairs $(a,b)$ from two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $a\neq b$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I have two sets $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{2,3,4\}$

How do I count the amount of pairs $(a,b)$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, such that $a\ne b$

This problem can easily be done on paper, but how can I solve this with combinatorics and more generally with larger sets.

Comment: Could you generalise the problem at all?

Comment: for above example, possible pair are (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,2),(3,4) but (2,2),(3,3) are not possible because they are present in both sets...so ans is 7.but how to solve in general way for long sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question can be answered like this:

Let $N$ be the total number of pairs.  Let $E$ be the number of pairs with both numbers equal.  Then $N - E$ is the number of pairs where the two numbers are not equal.

In this case, there are $3$ elements in $A$, and $3$ elements in $B$.  So, there are $N = |A| \times |B| = 3 \times 3 = 9$ pairs.

The two sets have two numbers in common.  That is, $E = |A \cap B| = 2$.  So, there will be $2$ pairs (elements of $A \times B$) where both numbers are identical (in this case, $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$).

So, our final answer will be $N - E = 9 - 2 = 7$.

In general: suppose that you want to find the number of pairs in $A \times B$ that do not consist of a repeated element.  The answer will be
$$
N - E = (|A|\times |B|) - |A \cap B|
$$